# Opensea Import smart contract not working for Polygon Testnet Mumbai

Tags: solidity, polygon, smartcontracts, nft, opensea

I get the following error when trying to use the import smart contract
https://testnets.opensea.io/get-listed/step-two

```
We couldn't find this contract. Please ensure that this is a valid ERC721 or ERC1155 contract deployed on Mumbai and that you have already minted items on the contract.
```

Everything is working fine with my smart contract I was able to mint and add it to my wallet.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong when importing to opensea?

Answer (score 0):

They're having testnet issues, possible cause of your problems.

[image]